# Open firefox browser using Selenium 3.5.2 , Python3.6

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I had installed python 3.6 and selenium 3.5.2 version,geckodriver.exe . But when i used below code not able to open fire fox

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
driver=webdriver.Firefox("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Selenium\\seleniumfirefoxdriver\\geckodriver.exe")
driver.set_page_load_timeout(20)
driver.get("www.google.com")`enter code here`
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
```

## Error shown as

```
NotADirectory Error:
[Win Error 267] The directory name is invalid: C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Selenium\\selenium firefoxdriver\\geckodriver.exe
```

Comment: Try with single quotes. Lets see if it works.
Also, there is difference in path that you wrote in code and in the error. Rename your folder name to seleniumfirefoxdriver instead of selenium firefoxdriver.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code-

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Desktop\Selenium\seleniumfirefoxdriver\geckodriver.exe')
```

If there is a space in folder name 'selenium firefoxdriver', rename that folder to 'seleniumfirefoxdriver'

Answer (score 0):

Try single  slash and folder name doesn't contain space either use _ or remove space in folder name **"selenium firefoxdriver"**. Make it **"selenium_firefoxdriver"** or **"SeleniumFirefoxdriver"**.

and then use this code:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:/Users/Desktop/Selenium/selenium_firefoxdriver/geckodriver.exe')
```

or

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:/Users/Desktop/Selenium/SeleniumFirefoxdriver/geckodriver.exe')
```